# JMeter(Bean Shell Sampler) + Git + Jenkins - Bean Sampler script not Reading the csv file

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, beanshell

I have API tests created in Jmeter and committed to the GIT branch.
All my JMeter tests executed from the Jenkins Pipeline job.

ISSUE:
In the Jmeter test, I am using a bean shell sampler that reads data from a CSV file. Refer to the below code.

```
LineNumberReader lineReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(new File("${csv}")));
String line = null;
int count = 1;
while ((line = lineReader.readLine()) != null) {
 String[] Test_details = line.split(",");
 props.put("Test_id_" + count, Test_details[0]);
 props.put("scenario_id_" + count, Test_details[1]);
 count++;
}
lineReader.close();
```

In this above script, CSV path referred from User-defined variables in Jmeter (csv = 'FilePath')

When I execute tests from Jenkins, data from the CSV file are not retrieved and tests are failing.

Note: When I execute from the local machine, data from CSV is retrieved and tests get passed.

While executing from Jenkins below CSV path is given in user-defined variables.
csv = apitests\src\test\jmeter\data\Testdata.csv

and below is the folder structure
[Folder Struture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6CFZ.png)

Comment: From the pop-up text for [tag:git]: *Also, do not use this tag for general programming questions that happen to involve a Git repository.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're running test via [JMeter Maven plugin](https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin) the test base directory (a.k.a [Java user.dir](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html)) looks like:

```
target/somerandomguid/jmeter/bin
```

so if you need to get the relative path to your file you need to get 4 levels up and then go to src/test/jmeter/data, something like:

```
new File("../../../../src/test/jmeter/data/Testdata.csv")
```

Also be aware that [starting from JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to be using JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it might be a good chance for the change. More information: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)